# Download maven dependencies programmatically

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, aether

I have been trying to download all maven dependencies programmatically via aether. I can get all the transitive dependencies (courtesy of the code from

`https://github.com/apache/maven-resolver/blob/master/maven-resolver-demos/maven-resolver-demo-snippets/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/resolver/examples/ResolveTransitiveDependencies.java`

however because it doesn't download any of the plugins needed by the dependency.

Since I am quite new to Maven, I might be missing something completely obvious here, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

If I try to download the dependecies for sonarqube plugin with ResolveTransitiveDependencies.java, I get the following correctly downloaded.

```
org\sonarsource\scanner\maven\sonar-maven-plugin\3.6.0.1398\sonar-maven-plugin-3.6.0.1398.jar
org\sonatype\plexus\plexus-sec-dispatcher\1.4\plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
org\sonatype\plexus\plexus-cipher\1.4\plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-utils\3.0.22\plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
org\sonarsource\scanner\api\sonar-scanner-api\2.12.0.1661\sonar-scanner-api-2.12.0.1661.jar
commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar
```

However it doesn't download any of the plugins that are part of the individual transitive dependency POM,s. Is there a way to do that from Aether ?

Comment: Why would you like to download them programmatically instead of letting Maven do it's job? What is the purpose of this? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with just doing a mvn compile?

Comment: @khmarbaise - Since the team is working on an air gap network, there is a feeling that it is preferable to download the dependencies as and when it is required, outside the maven environment. Since `dependency:go-offline` requires a Maven project, the idea is to have a JSON file with the required dependency and then download it with a program outside of maven - if that makes sense ??

Comment: Simplest solution is using a repository manager build your application and replicate that state into the internal network..easy less work...Creating supplemental files with dependencies is not a good idea cause it duplicates information which is already there in the pom file...

Comment: @khmarbaise - not sure if I understand fully. The problem is that the application is not available on the external network to build. The POM can be copied, so the idea is to use the pom to download all direct and plugin dependencies, and then copy that over to the internal network repository manager, which then can be used to build the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Jeka library (https://jeka.dev) to accomplish this.

```
import dev.jeka.core.api.depmanagement.*;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.List;

import static dev.jeka.core.api.depmanagement.JkJavaDepScopes.*;

public class SampleDepDownload {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JkDependencySet deps = JkDependencySet.of()
                .and("com.googlecode.playn:playn-core:1.4")
                .and("com.threerings:tripleplay:1.4")
                .withDefaultScopes(COMPILE_AND_RUNTIME);
        JkDependencyResolver resolver = JkDependencyResolver.of(JkRepo.ofMavenCentral());
        List<Path> libs = resolver.resolve(deps, RUNTIME).getFiles().getEntries();
    }
}
```