# How to download dependencies from maven center (or some special repositories) by Java code?

Tags: java, maven

I'm writing an application which can load jars as plugins. Plugins may depend on some common libraries such as Gson, and if every plugin author pack their dependencies which can be downloaded from maven center (or some special repositories) into jars, it'll be redundant.

In order to make it more graceful, I want to allow plugin authors to write their dependencies info down in plugin metadata file, so that the application can download it automatically.

How to download dependencies from maven center (or some special repositories) by Java code? I want to download not only its jars (recent or elder version), but also its version info, so that the application can manage libraries.

Comment: Redundant in what sense?  Frankly, an application that downloads its JAR dependencies rather than having them in the installer, or whatever, seems like a recipe for fragility.  In 2022, disk space is cheap and network bandwidth, but hand-holding naive users through problems caused by failed dependency downloads would be expensive.

Comment: But it that is what you want, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55938870

Comment: Or you could use (embed) Maven or Ivy to download the JARs.

Comment: This can get tricky if different plug-ins require different versions of the same library.

Comment: Meh ... classloaders ... waves hands ... :-)   But you are correct.  If you want the application to be able to do its own dependency resolution and downloading, then it needs to deal with *all* of the problems that would normally be addressed with build-time dependency resolution.

Comment: Another thing to look at would be the OSGI framework used by Eclipse, etc.

Comment: If you really like to deal with all that sutff (which I strongly recommend not to do; already some arguments given) you could start: https://maven.apache.org/resolver/ but I would build such things at build time and package some kind installer that does it.. not during run time of your app...The other question can you give more details about the application?

Comment: Don’t reinvent the wheel - use a tried and tested technology.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Maven-Artifact-Resolver](https://maven.apache.org/resolver/) library. - This library can not only download the artifacts, but is also able to resolve dependency trees. So it is may be more than you need.

*(Under the hood, Apache Maven Artifact Resolver was former a project called Eclipse Aether.
(And "Eclipse Aether" was former "Sonatype Aether".))*

There  is also [maven-archeologist](https://github.com/square/maven-archeologist), but I have not used it.