# Maven Plugin - how to add a dependency to an existing MavenProject object

Tags: maven, dependencies

I am writing a Maven plugin. Within the plugin I would like to extend my primary MavenProject with and additional dependency and get all dependencies copied to my local project.

Based on some "internet research" I started with the following code:

//to add the dependency

```
Artifact poi = artifactFactory.createArtifact("org.apache.poi", "poi", "5.1.0",Artifact.SCOPE_COMPILE, "jar");
            
Set set = new HashSet(project.getDependencyArtifacts() );
set.add( poi );
project.setDependencyArtifacts( set );
```

//to get the dependencies "copied"

```
executeMojo(plugin(groupId("org.apache.maven.plugins"), artifactId("maven-dependency-plugin"), version("2.8")),goal("copy-dependencies"),
configuration(element(name("outputDirectory"), unpackDependenciesDirectory.getAbsolutePath()),
element(name("includeTypes"), "jar"),
element(name("includeScope"), "compile")),
executionEnvironment(project, session, buildPluginManager));
```

However only the original dependencies are downloaded - not the new one.
What do I miss? What do I need to do to extend the list of dependencies?
(would expect something like updating my project? but there is no such "method")

Further I have see that setDependencyArtifacts is set to deprected. But I haven't found any documentation why - so any insights are also welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why should a plugin add dependencies to a project... ? Those dependencies are resolved before plugins etc. will be executed ... Also the setDependenciesArtifacts is deprecated because this modell is immutable...

Comment: Which problem should your plugin solve?

Comment: @JFabianMeier first thanks for your answer. 
My goal is to build a package for "IBM App Connect Enterprise". Typically I have here two "projects" - one for the App Connect App and a second for the Java related part. 
Both project / parts has an own pom - but because of other constraints I can not do a standard multi modul build (...just trust me ...). 
Thus perhaps another question: is there perhaps an option to "load" the other pom within my plugin and add it to the overall project? Or is this also immutable?

Comment: Make multi module build... which will solve the problem. The constrains will not solve the problem...saying I can not do a multi module will not help yourself nor your eployer or alike ...

Comment: @ChrWeiss I think you are really on the wrong track. You cannot add a POM during the build. If you cannot merge the two projects into one multi-module project, why not just declare a dependency in one project on the other project?

Answer (score 2):

First of all thanks Fabian an Karl-Heinz for your feedback and input.
And yes you are right it is

1. not a good idea at all and
2. not possible to change / update the dependencies within a Maven Plugin.

(at least in the current maven version; not sure if it was possible in earlier times, as I have see some code snippets that at least suggest it).

Thus I ended up with the solution suggested by Fabian above - to simply define a dependency (of type pom) in the parent project.

Anyhow: if anybody has the requirement to resolve and download additional maven (or ivy) dependencies I could now also recommend Jeka ;-) . See:

- [Download maven dependencies programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55938870/download-maven-dependencies-programmatically)
- https://github.com/jeka-dev

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add dependencies to the projects during the build. The dependencies are resolved before any plugin runs.

You can update or change dependencies with separate Maven goals, like those of the maven dependency plugin.